# Avoiding double mutable reference when updating enum variant data in Rust

Tags: rust, struct, enums

(using rust 1.74.1)

I have this setup:

```rust
struct DataA {
    a: i32
}

struct DataB {
    b: i32
}

enum Data {
    TypeA(DataA),
    TypeB(DataB),
    // TypeC etc...
}

struct Struct {
    field: i32,
    // other fields
    data: Data,
}

impl Struct {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> i32 {
        self.field += 5;
        return 5;
    }
}
```

And I'd like to implement a method (`bar()`) for `Struct`, that sets `TypeA(DataA)`'s `a` to the return value of `foo()`, and does nothing if `Struct`.`data` is not of `TypeA`.

Initially, I tried

```
fn bar(&mut self) {
    let Data::TypeA(data) = &mut self.data else {
        return;
    };
    data.a = self.foo();
}
```

But this doesn't work because I `` cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time ``.

After a bit of trial an error I found

```rust
let Data::TypeA(..) = self.data else {
    return;
};
self.data = Data::TypeA(DataA{ a: self.foo() });
```

which works but is verbose and cumbersome (e.g. adding more fields to DataA).

Mind that `foo()` will never mutate `Struct`'s `data` and that it must be run *after* checking if the type matches.

Is there a way better way to write this without changing the setup?
If not, what's the most idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Be aware that `foo` has `&mut self`, which means that it **could** mutate `self.data`. So I think `foo` is the problem here - it is conceptually unsound. So yes, your last code snippet is the only possible option, but the `if let` is pointless because `foo` could change the data type.

I think a better solution would be an architectural rework of your struct layout, but of course I can't help with that as I don't know your actual non-minimized problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mind that `foo()` will never mutate `Struct`'s `data` and that it must be run after checking if the type matches.

I think this is the main problem. While you say that `foo` never does that, your API does not reflect that. If it would, the compiler would let you do that.

If you encapsulate `field` in its own data type and move the `foo` function there, you effectively told the compiler that you only modify `field` in this function.

```rust
struct DataA {
    a: i32,
}

struct DataB {
    b: i32,
}

enum Data {
    TypeA(DataA),
    TypeB(DataB),
    // TypeC etc...
}

struct FieldData {
    field: i32,
}

impl FieldData {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> i32 {
        self.field += 5;
        return 5;
    }
}

struct Struct {
    field: FieldData,
    // other fields
    data: Data,
}

impl Struct {
    fn bar(&mut self) {
        if let Data::TypeA(data) = &mut self.data {
            data.a = self.field.foo();
        }
    }
}
```

Splitting a struct into multiple parts is a pretty common solution for issues like this.

---

If you need read-only access to some other parts of the struct, like the previous `DataA` object, you can pass it in via function parameter:

```rust
struct DataA {
    a: i32,
}

struct DataB {
    b: i32,
}

enum Data {
    TypeA(DataA),
    TypeB(DataB),
    // TypeC etc...
}

struct FieldData {
    field: i32,
}

impl FieldData {
    fn foo(&mut self, previous_data: &DataA) -> i32 {
        self.field += 5;
        return 5;
    }
}

struct Struct {
    field: FieldData,
    // other fields
    data: Data,
}

impl Struct {
    fn bar(&mut self) {
        if let Data::TypeA(data) = &mut self.data {
            data.a = self.field.foo(data);
        }
    }
}
```